# R loop function for selecting an element in multiple objects

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm using the Google Trends R package to perform several queries of keywords like so:

```
trends1 <- gtrends(keyword="compare", gprop=channel,geo="AU", time=time, category=249)
trends2 <- gtrends(keyword="switch", gprop=channel,geo="AU", time=time, category=249)
trends3 <- gtrends(keyword="change", gprop=channel,geo="AU", time=time, category=249)
```

I'm only interested in the *interest over time* results, so I single them out:

```
time_trend1 <- trends1$interest_over_time
time_trend2 <- trends2$interest_over_time
time_trend3 <- trends3$interest_over_time
```

But I have 60 of these (and many more to add). I want to write a repeat loop (I think):

```
#select only interest over time
x <- 0
repeat {
time_trend(x+1) <- trends(x+1)$interest_over_time
if (x == 61){break}
}
```

but I get the error: Error in trends(x + 1) : could not find function "trends"

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data in a list using `ls` + `mget`, use `lapply` to iterate over each list and get `"interest_over_time"` element of each list.

```
total_list <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'trends\\d+')), `[[`, "interest_over_time")
```

`total_list` would give you list of dataframes. It is better to keep data in a list since it easier to manage and does not clutter the environment with lot of objects. However, if you want data separately for each we can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(total_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

To drop certain columns, we can do :

```
total_list <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'trends\\d+')), function(x) {
         data <- x$interest_over_time
         data[setdiff(names(data), c("geo","category","time"))]
})
```

Comment: could we use tidyeval here?

Comment: I am not sure how tidyeval would be used here.

Comment: this is great, but how would I then add/ remove columns of data from the list of dfs? i.e. drop "geo","category","time",etc...

Comment: @DrPaul We can use `setdiff`, check updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `lapply` to iterate over a list of keywords and extract the requested element like this:

```r
library(gtrendsR)
time <- "today+5-y"
channel <- "web"
keywords <- list("compare", "switch", "change")
trends <- setNames(lapply(keywords, function(x) gtrends(keyword=x, 
  gprop=channel, geo="AU", time=time, category=249)), keywords)
lapply(trends, `[[`, "interest_over_time")
#> $compare
#>           date hits geo      time keyword gprop category
#> 1   2015-04-26   25  AU today+5-y compare   web      249
#> 2   2015-05-03   26  AU today+5-y compare   web      249
#> 3   2015-05-10   41  AU today+5-y compare   web      249
#> 4   2015-05-17   29  AU today+5-y compare   web      249
#> 5   2015-05-24   32  AU today+5-y compare   web      249
# ...
#> 260 2020-04-12    9  AU today+5-y compare   web      249
#> 
#> $switch
#>           date hits geo      time keyword gprop category
#> 1   2015-04-26    0  AU today+5-y  switch   web      249
#> 2   2015-05-03    0  AU today+5-y  switch   web      249
#> 3   2015-05-10    0  AU today+5-y  switch   web      249
#> 4   2015-05-17    0  AU today+5-y  switch   web      249
#> 5   2015-05-24    0  AU today+5-y  switch   web      249
# ...
#> 260 2020-04-12    0  AU today+5-y  switch   web      249
#> 
#> $change
#>           date hits geo      time keyword gprop category
#> 1   2015-04-26   45  AU today+5-y  change   web      249
#> 2   2015-05-03   68  AU today+5-y  change   web      249
#> 3   2015-05-10   23  AU today+5-y  change   web      249
#> 4   2015-05-17   52  AU today+5-y  change   web      249
#> 5   2015-05-24   76  AU today+5-y  change   web      249
# ...
#> 260 2020-04-12   38  AU today+5-y  change   web      249
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Edit**:
It may be easiest to further manipulate the data once the individual list elements get combined into a data.table, tibble or data.frame. Shown here is an example of how to remove unwanted columns. To subset by keyword, one could do, e.g. `res[keyword=="compare"]`

```r
library(gtrendsR)
library(data.table)
time <- "today+5-y"
channel <- "web"
keywords <- list("compare", "switch", "change")
trends <- setNames(lapply(keywords, function(x) gtrends(keyword=x, 
  gprop=channel, geo="AU", time=time, category=249)), keywords)
res <- rbindlist(lapply(trends, `[[`, "interest_over_time"))
res[,-c("geo","category","time")]
#>            date hits keyword gprop
#>   1: 2015-04-26   25 compare   web
#>   2: 2015-05-03   26 compare   web
#>   3: 2015-05-10   41 compare   web
#>   4: 2015-05-17   29 compare   web
#>   5: 2015-05-24   32 compare   web
#>  ---                              
#> 776: 2020-03-15   51  change   web
#> 777: 2020-03-22   27  change   web
#> 778: 2020-03-29   20  change   web
#> 779: 2020-04-05    0  change   web
#> 780: 2020-04-12   35  change   web
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>